# Azure DevOps pipelines - get build number of previous stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yml pipeline with 2 stages:

```
- stage:
- stage:
```

My second stage needs to refer to the `$(Build.BuildNumber)` of the previous stage. How can this be achieved? My understanding is output variables are scoped to the same stage and can't be used across-stages.

Trying to pull from stageDependencies:

```
stages:
  - stage: BuildPublish
    displayName: "Build & Publish"
    jobs:
      - job: BuildPublishJob
        displayName: "Build & Publish"
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Recording MSI version"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=msiVersion;isOutput=true]$(Build.BuildNumber)"
            name: MsiVersion
          - script: echo $(MsiVersion.msiVersion)
            name: echovar

  - stage: DeployInstallerTest
    displayName: "Deploy Installer Test"
    jobs:
    - job:
      displayName: "Deploy Installer Test"
      steps:
      - task: AzurePowerShell@5
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'Spektrix Non-Prod'
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          Inline: |
            $msiVersion = stageDependencies.BuildPublish.BuildPublishJob.outputs['MsiVersion.msiVersion']
          azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Fails with:

*##[error]The term 'stageDependencies.BuildPublish.BuildPublishJob.outputs[MsiVersion.msiVersion]' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It changed recently:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Foo."
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes" #The variable doThing is set to true
      name: DetermineResult
    - script: echo $(DetermineResult.doThing)
      name: echovar
  - job: JA_2
    dependsOn: JA
    condition: eq(dependencies.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes')
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Bar."

#stage B runs if DetermineResult task set doThing variable n stage A
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: JB
    condition: eq(stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes') #map doThing and check if true
    variables:
      varFromStageA: $[ stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'] ]
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Hello world stage B first job"
    - script: echo $(varFromStageA)
```

However, please be aware that `stageDependencies` is not available in condition at **stage** level. Of course you can use `stageDependencies` not only in condition.

Comment: Many thanks. If I get "The term 'stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs[Myscript.myar]' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." - could this be related to versioning? This is a build pipeline I'm using.

Comment: Can you add your YAML to question?

Comment: Sure thing I've included only the relevant parts. MsiVersion.msiVersion is successfully echo'd at the end of the first stage.

Comment: Please check my update. You will find an example how to use variable not only in `condition`.